# what is the correct way to join three tables where rows that can appear on one table will show results in others

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following scenario

CTE with result 1:

```
| src__id | Period | Amount_A |   |
|---------|--------|----------|---|
| id1     | Q1     | 2        |   |
```

CTE with Result2:

```
| src__id | Period | Amount_B |   |
|---------|--------|----------|---|
| id1     | Q1     | 9        |   |
| id2     | Q2     | 1        |   |
```

CTE with Result3:

```
| src__id | Period | Amount_C |   |
|---------|--------|----------|---|
| id2     | Q2     | 4        |   |
```

The desired result is:

```
| src__id | Period | A | B | C | A+B-C |   |
|---------|--------|---|---|---|-------|---|
| id1     | Q1     | 2 | 9 |   | 11    |   |
| id2     | Q2     |   | 1 | 4 | -3    |   |
```

Things that are important to mention:
"src__id" and "Period" exist on all the CTE results and on the original table that I am using to get those CTEs

How can I achieve it using full join ? or maybe I am not using the correct type of join for the job?

the original join that I am doing is:

```
Select A
full join B on A.src__id = B.src__id
full join C on A.src__id = C.src__id
```

Getting this:

```
| src__id | Period | A | B | C | A+B-C |
|---------|--------|---|---|---|-------|
| id1     | Q1     | 2 | 9 |   | 11    |
| id2     | Q2     |   | 1 |   | 1     |
| id2     | Q2     |   |   | 4 | -4    |
```

one example of join that gets the correct result is (need explanation why):
I have a feeling that this would not catch all the edge cases,
one that I can think of:
where the 1st table does not have id1 and the others do have it

```
Select A
full join B on A.src__id = B.src__id and A.Period = B.Period
full join C on B.src__id = C.src__id
```

The join that gets the wrong answer but seems logical to me is:

```
Select A
full join B on A.src__id = B.src__id and A.Period = B.Period
full join C on B.src__id = C.src__id and B.Period = C.Period
```

[fiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?id=2baeac98-0d4e-4c1c-9ae5-e06a94057901)

Comment: You can UNION ALL the tables, and GROUP BY the result.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I edited the question and added a fiddle

Comment: @jarlh can you please provide the query that solves it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [immediately pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77867813/what-is-the-correct-way-to-join-three-tables-where-rows-that-can-appear-on-one-t/77867946#comment137276129_77867813) by [@jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh), you can merge these sources with a [`union all`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) and aggregate on that: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WTgSIj_9)

```
with result1(src__id,period,amount_a) as (values ('id1','Q1',2) ),
     result2(src__id,period,amount_b) as (values ('id1','Q1',9),
                                                 ('id2','Q2',1) ),
     result3(src__id,period,amount_c) as (values ('id2','Q2',4) ),
     all_results(src__id,period,amount_a,amount_b,amount_c) as 
  (          select src__id,period,amount_a,null::int,null::int from result1
   union all select src__id,period,null,    amount_b, null      from result2
   union all select src__id,period,null,    null,     amount_c  from result3)
select src__id,
       period,
       sum(amount_a) amount_a,
       sum(amount_b) amount_b,
       sum(amount_c) amount_c,
       sum( coalesce(amount_a,0)
           +coalesce(amount_b,0)
           -coalesce(amount_c,0)) as "A+B-C" 
from all_results
group by src__id,period;
```

| src__id | period | amount_a | amount_b | amount_c | A+B-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | Q1 | 2 | 9 | *null* | 11 |
| id2 | Q2 | *null* | 1 | 4 | -3 |

That being said, your approach with `full outer join` works just as well, giving the exact same results: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lzf-sBt4)

```sql
with result1(src__id,period,amount_a) as (values ('id1','Q1',2) ),
     result2(src__id,period,amount_b) as (values ('id1','Q1',9),
                                                 ('id2','Q2',1) ),
     result3(src__id,period,amount_c) as (values ('id2','Q2',4))
select src__id,
       period,
       sum(amount_a) amount_a,
       sum(amount_b) amount_b,
       sum(amount_c) amount_c,
       sum(coalesce(amount_a,0)+coalesce(amount_b,0)-coalesce(amount_c,0)) as "A+B-C" 
from result1 
full outer join result2 using (src__id,period)
full outer join result3 using (src__id,period)
group by src__id,period;
```

[`JOIN USING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.4.3.1.1) lets you shorten things:

> While `JOIN ON` produces all columns from `T1` followed by all columns from `T2`, `JOIN USING` produces one output column for each of the listed column pairs (in the listed order), followed by any remaining columns from `T1`, followed by any remaining columns from `T2`.

With `JOIN ON` you'd have to `coalesce()` all `src__id` and `period` columns manually before being able to `group by` them like this: [demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/j71gE7Lq).

Comment: that means I have to use "null" to select it ?

Comment: @Eitank `result1` doesn't natively have `b` and `c` columns at all, so that way you're adding them but leaving them empty. This gives you a row that has all fields of `result1`, `result2` and `result3` and by aligning all three sources this way, you can merge them into one, then `select...group by` in the final, outer query.

Comment: As to *"edge cases, one that I can think of: where the 1st table does not have id1 and the others do have it"* - no need to worry about that. As you can see, that's exactly the case for `id2` - the first table doesn't have it, the others do, and that's exactly the point of using a `full outer join`. A `left join` would hide anything absent from leftmost tables, `right join` from the rightmost. An `inner` eliminates all but common, a `full outer` keeps all.

Comment: is there a way to translate the "using" to "on" ?

Comment: `USING (src__id, period)` means just `ON (result1.src__id, result1.period)=(result2.src__id, result2.period)` but the `ON` variant will also bring both result1's and result2's columns to the output for you to resolve, so you'll have to then merge them with a `coalesce()`. I've demonstrated that in the [3rd demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/j71gE7Lq). Bottom line is, you *can* but it's longer and not worth it.

Comment: ok I see what you mean, thanks!

Comment: We had another example where only the join on solution worked, you can take a look here and this scenario happens when id is null
https://dbfiddle.uk/pkdwHbQz